# Simple question about IF statement

Tags: php

I just wonder how to check if there is a value in a column in a database table? The column is named `star` and I want to check if it has a value of 1 if not don't do anything.

```
while($row01 = $res01->fetch_object()) {

    if ($res01->star[$row01] == 1) { ??????????

    }

}
```

I use thise WHILE LOOP to fetch info from a table about some objects. For some objects I have a column named STAR that is 1 och NULL. While I build up the HTML-code into variables I in this loop, I also check if the object has 1 in the STAR column and if yes I create another variable with some HTML-code to use in the list of all the objects in the table.

But when I use  if($row01->star == '1') it's not working and I don't know why!? When I use this it's like, yes all objects has 1, but there is only a few that has 1, the rest has NULL value. Sorry, but I have to leave the computer for some houres, but I hope to solve this later today! Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the manual on the proper notation : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php You don't need to treat it as an array index. It's an object.

Comment: You need to show your query code and a sample of the information in the database.

Answer (score 5):

Close, but you're referring to the column wrong.

```
if ($row01->star == 1) { /* do things */ }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working! It's like I get the yes for all rows in the table?! I have either 1 or NULL in the fields and the type is INT. What could be wrong?

Comment: @3D-kreativ I would check if you're getting the columns/table correctly then. Use if($res01->num_rows) to check if you have anything returned.

Comment: Can you do a print_r of $row01 for us?

Comment: @3D-kreativ Can you edit your post with the results? Try if($row01->star == '1')